# How to convert Stream of chunks to regular Stream in Fs2

Tags: scala, fs2

For example:

`chunked = Stream(1, 2, 3).chunks
val regular = ???`

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I've found it [here](https://youtu.be/B1wb4fIdtn4?t=4366):

`val regular = chunked.flatMap(c => Stream.chunk(c))`

Answer (score 0):

It probably didn't exist when the question was asked, but in recent versions of `fs2` there is a combinator for exactly that:

```scala
val regular = chunked.unchunks
```